# Javascript simulating Shortest Job First, mapping time to arrival time

Tags: javascript, jquery, operating-system

I am trying to simulate the shortest job first technique of the operating system,
and I am currently stuck up on mapping the time to which process has arrived.

I have this array of objects

```
var arr = 
[
  {
    "job"      : "J1",
    "at"       : 3
  },
  {
    "job"      : "J2",
    "at"       : 0
  },
  {
    "job"      : "J3",
    "at"       : 5
  },
  {
    "job"      : "J4",
    "at"       : 3
  }
]
```

The first thing I did was to sort out the array according to arrival time `at`

```
function compare(a,b) {
  if (a.at < b.at)
     return -1;
  if (a.at > b.at)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

sorted = arr.sort(compare);
```

Now I wanted to store it in a table, so that:

```
-------------------------
|    Time   |  Process  |
-------------------------
|     0     |     ?     |
-------------------------
|     1     |     ?     |
-------------------------
|     2     |     ?     |
-------------------------
|     3     |     ?     |
-------------------------
|         ...           |
-------------------------
|         ...           |
-------------------------
|         ...           |
-------------------------
```

What I did is to find out the object that has the greatest `at`

```
maxTime = 0;
$.each(arr, function(k, v){
  maxTime = v.at > maxTime ? v.at : maxTime;
});
```

And started looping

```
var row = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= maxTime; i++) {
  row.push('<tr>');
  row.push('<td>' + i);
  var arrived = true;
  for (var j = 0; j < sorted.length; j++) {
    arrived = false;
    if(sorted[j].at == i) {
      row.push('<td>' + sorted[j].job);
    }
  };
  if(!arrived) {
     row.push('<td>');
  }
};
$('table').append(row.join(''));
```

And this what happens [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p3j7B/). If you can see that additional cell created, I can't find what am I missing. Maybe later I'll ask about the burst time.

Answer (score 0):

I simplified it , removed the boolean, and just push in whatever values is equal

```
for (var i = 0; i <= maxTime; i++) {
  row.push('<tr>');
  row.push('<td>' + i);
  var arrivedJobs = "";
  for (var j = 0; j < sorted.length; j++) {
    if(sorted[j].at == i) {
      arrivedJobs += sorted[j].job + "," ;
    }
  };
  row.push('<td>' + arrivedJobs.replace(/(^,)|(,$)/g, ""));
};
```